# Convert CString to Enum type in MFC(VC++)?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

how to Convert CString to Enum type in MFC(VC++) ?

I have one method which take input parameter as Enum but i am passing Cstring value to it how i can convert it to enum.

```
CString strFolderType = strFolderType.Right(strFolderType.GetLength()-(fPos+1));
m_strFolderType = strFolderType ;
```

I have one method as

```
ProtocolIdentifier(eFolderType iFolderType)

where enum eFolderType
{
    eFTP = 1,
    eCIFS,
    eBOTH
};
```

now when i am calling like this :

```
ProtocolIdentifier(m_strFolderType);
```

It says cannot convert CString to eFolderType ...

How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is `m_strFolderType` a string? It seems like it should be an `eFolderType`.

There is no automatic way to convert a `CString` to an `enum` (which is really an integer). The values `eFTP`, `eCIFS`, and `eBOTH` are not strings and the compiler will not treat them as such.

Passing an integer as a string is ugly. You should pass an `eFolderType` as the argument. If you must pass a string (perhaps it came from some serialization that returned a string), you will have to do something like this:

```
eFolderType result = /* whichever should be the default*/ ;
if (m_strFolderType == _T("eFTP")) {
    result = eFTP;
} else if (m_strFolderType == _T("eCIFS")) {
    result = eCIFS;
} else if (m_strFolderType == _T("eBOTH")) {
    result = eBOTH;
} else {
    // Invalid value was passed: either use the default value or
    // treat this as an error, depending on your requirements.
}
```